# Why does VB.NET show a (0,0) element in my array after I've filled it with data from Excel?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

The following code will result in an x(,) matrix containing array elements transferred from Excel, that when looked at using QuickWatch, will indicate a zero-based array.  However, the array will be one-based and the (0,0) element shown in QuickWatch will not be accessible.

I believe this behavior to be a bug, since QuickWatch shows that a (0,0) element exists, which truly does not -- since it is not accessible.

The following code will spawn the x(,) array that is in question, and when viewed with QuickWatch will show a (0,0) element.

To implement the code, add an OperFileDialog1 to your form, and paste the following code into e.g. a button.  You will need to ensure there are valid string or numerical values cells A1, A2, B1, B2 in the Excel that is opened. At run-time, for some reason, the element x(0,0) is unreadable, even though there will be data shown in the x(0,0) element when viewed with QuickWatch:

```
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim filename As String
Dim x(,) As Object
Dim myx(,) As Object
With OpenFileDialog1
    .FileName = "*.*"
    .CheckFileExists = True
    .ShowReadOnly = True
    .Filter = "Excel 2010 *.xlxs|*.xlxs|Excel 2003-2007 *.xls|*.xls"
    If .ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'Load file
        filename = .FileName
    End If
End With


' Create new Application.
Dim rXL As New Excel.Application
Dim rWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim rSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rRng As Excel.Range
rWB = rXL.Workbooks.Open(filename)

For i = 1 To 1 '  rWB.Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = rWB.Sheets(i)
    Dim r As Excel.Range = sheet.UsedRange
    If r.Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit For
    Dim eCellArray As System.Array = r.Value
    ReDim x(r.Rows.Count, r.Columns.Count)
    x = r.Value
    rRng = Nothing
Next
ReDim myx(x.GetLength(0) + 1, x.GetLength(1) + 1)
For i = 0 To x.GetLength(0)
    For j = 0 To x.GetLength(1)
        myx(i + 1, j + 1) = x(i, j)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Could you add a short but complete sample code that shows this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This works in vb.net 2008:

```
Dim x(100, 100) As Object
x(0, 0) = "asdf"
MsgBox(x(0, 0))
```

You may be assigning the string to the wrong array element or you may be assigning the correct array element something other than a single string, such as a string array.

Comment: There is an entry at MSDN's forum on an array transfer mismatch between Excel and VB.NET 2010: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/8155cfa8-7b9f-4a55-ba46-45bddcb77779